# Why does this c program output strange characters?

Tags: c

The following C code, after compiling in MinGW under windows, gives output that I can't understand.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    char s[100];
    int i,c;
    for(i=0;i<100-1&&(c=getchar())!=EOF&&c!='\n';++i)
        s[i]=c;
    if(c=='\n'){
        s[i]=c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i]='p';
    printf("%s",s);
}
```

The output is

[image]

Why are there strange characters after "p"? What do they mean?

Comment: `s` is not null-terminated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings in c need to be null-terminated. This is to mean that the last character of the string always has to be `\0`.

This is how you program knows where to stop reading the string since it is a simple array of `char` that carries no length information like you would be used to in higher level languages like c++.

**Edit** : The strange characters are the result of the memory after the valid characters being read. Since that memory does not contain valid characters it can be interpreted in various unpredictable ways.

Comment: Thank you! OK, I know. But I want to know why it output these strange characters, where are they?

Comment: When the array `s` is created, its contents are garbage. You've initilalized only part of it; the rest contains garbage, which is what's being printed. If you're "lucky", there happens to be a null character somewhere in the garbage, and `printf` will stop printing at that point. If not, it will continue past the end of `s`, causing *undefined behavior* (it may print more garbage from memory, or it may crash, or worse).

Comment: @KeithThompson Thank you for your detailed mechanism explanation.

Comment: @user15964 If you feel that my answer is satisfactory please accept it so it will stop showing up in the unanswered section.

Answer (score 0):

You are additionally potentially attempting to assign a value outside of your declared range of `s`. You define `s[100]` that gives you 100 chars at `s[0]` through `s[99]`. Your code can attempt to assign `s[100]` which is undefined.. Specifically:

```
for(i=0;i<100-1&&(c=getchar())!=EOF&&c!='\n';++i)
    s[i]=c;
```

The for loop increments `i` from `98` to `99` and terminates with `i=99`. (i.e. `i` is no longer less than `100-1` so the loop terminates on that clause.) Look what can happen next. If `c` is a newline, you assign `s[99]='\n'` and increment `i` **(++i)** to `100`:

```
if(c=='\n'){ 
    s[i]=c;
    ++i;
}
```

Still OK, but you can't assign `s[i]` again. You then assign `s[100]='p';`. **Kaboom!**

```
s[i]='p';
```

(now it doesn't fail with a kaboom every time -- think about it as a timebomb that could go off at any moment -- randomly). Combine this with the other answer and you should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

It is always good practice to initialize the array in the program before you start using
the array. This will avoid printing the junk chars in these type of cases.

bzero(s, sizeof(char)*100);